# Adding Zookeeper Nodes for Clickhouse From 3 to 5

Tags: apache-zookeeper, clickhouse

I was testing out adding 2 zookeeper nodes to a clickhouse cluster. However it seems whenever I had 2 new nodes all the tables that were created with 3 zookeeper nodes turns into read only mode and there's no way to recover them. Has any one have any experience adding 2 new zookeeper nodes?

I should mention that it seems to be when I take down the leader is when the table goes into read only mode.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that

```
echo stats|nc zk_ip_new_server 2181
```

shows

```
Mode: follower
```

or

```
Mode: leader
```

before adding these 2 ZK servers into CH configs.

Comment: hi Denny, yes the way i was doing it, i dropped the 2 followers -> changed config to have 5 zookeepers -> add 2 new zookeepers -> drop leader -> add 5 zookeeper to config for leader